# Javascript Regex replace specific string with specific constraints

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string like so: `{{q:6}}`

I need to be able to make a regex to take it and turn it into this:
"Question Here"

The Regex would need to ignore `{{q:` and would need to be [0-9] for any number from 0 to 100.

```
var final_value = value.replace(/^{{q:([0-9]+)$}}/g, 'question');
```

Using it in this context ^, but this isn't working.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Final working answer:

```
value.replace(/\{\{q:([0-9]+)\}\}/g, question);
```

Comment: The `$}}` part doesn't make sense, since that means "end-of-string, followed by `}}`". Naturally, the end of the string can never be followed by more characters. :-)

Comment: Your "final answer" is incorrect (even if it works). See @meetamit's answer, my comments, and http://jsfiddle.net/4f86N/

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's working, but thanks for the comment!

Comment: @K_G based on your other comments, {{q:6}} is actually a sub-string, not the whole string. So the issue is actually with the question ;-)

Comment: So the actual correct answer for you is @meetamit's last comment. Again, the \ are not needed: http://jsfiddle.net/4f86N/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String final_value = "{{q:6}}\n{{q:39}}".replaceAll("\\{\\{q:([0-9]+)\\}\\}", "Question: $1");
System.out.println(final_value);
```

This is java, a general answer would be: `"/\{\{q:([0-9]+)\}\}/g"`

Answer (score 1):

The `$` sign needs to go AFTER the `}}`

```
"{{q:6}}".replace(/^{{q:([0-9]+)}}$/g, 'question');// <= yields "question"
```

Comment: This worked (in Chrome) WITHOUT escaping the `{`. I was surprised, but there you have it.

Comment: this does not work actually, and I am using Chrome.  I have a string of {{q:6}} and this is part of a larger string.  it does not return "question".

Comment: Yeah, in a larger string you need to remove the `^` and `$`. `"sometext{{q:6}}moretext".replace(/{{q:([0-9]+)}}/g, 'question');` yields `"sometextquestionmoretext"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your `{` and `}`.

Also if you want to limit from 0 to 100 inclusive, then you need to change:

```
[0-9]+
```

which will accept any string of digits to something like:

```
[1]?\d?\d
```

Which will accept `1` or not, a single digit (or not) and then a single digit.

Edit: and also @ruakh's comment about your placement of `$` applies.

Comment: No you don't need to escape {}. The issue is with the position of the $ character.